# Understanding VMFS storage usage

Tags: storage, vmware-esx

please help me understand something regarding used and available space on a datastore holding thin provisioned vmdk files.

Im having an ESX 4.1 U3 VMFS 3.48 datastore called "storage1".
This is 1.09TB

On this datastore there is one folder, with one vmdk file: pc.vmdk. This is a THIN provisioned WS2008R2 partition at 1TB (the data partition).
1TB in the configuration and properties of vSphere and 1TB (apx.) useable inside the VM.

Heres the assumption - the file pc.vmdk is stated as:

1.073.742.00,00KB Provisioned size

1.063.494.000,00KB Size (actual)

So lets agree on that datastore is 1,09TB and that is: 1,09 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1.170.378.588,16KB

So the total storage space of the datastore is:
1.170.378.588,16 KB

The total usage of the VMDK on the datastore is: 
1.073.742.000,00KB

So the difference is: 1.170.378.588,16 minus 1.073.742.00,00 = 96.636.588,16KB = 96GB.

This would mean, that even though my THIN provisioned vmdk is running full, there will always be 96GB available on the datastore, correct?

Thank you for your time.